# arbor.js for annotated illustration

Tags: javascript, canvas, arbor.js

I'm hoping to use arbor.js as a way of creating annotated illustrations.

The plan:

- Fixed size canvas
- Draw image to canvas – as an example i've used the silhouette of head.
- Then have a mixture of fixed and floating nodes.

---

```
var data = {
               nodes:{
                 brain-position:{},
                 brain-text:{'color':'green','shape':'dot','label':'brain'},
                 mouth-position:{},
mouth-text{'color':'green','shape':'dot','label':'mouth'},
               }, 
               edges:{
                 brain-position:{ brain-text },
mouth-position:{mouth-text}
               }
             };
            sys.graft(data);
```

The problems i'm having is that when I try to create a statically positioned nodeBox eg.
`nodeBoxes[node.name] = [50,50, w,w]` it breaks the link to other linked nodes.

I'm tinkering with halfvis/src/renderer.js file from the downloaded arbor file.

Many thanks

[image: annotated illustration]

**EDIT**

Below is an additional image that hopefully visualises the functionality I'm attempting. Probably should have done this first :)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodeBoxes`, in the halfvis example, is an array used to work out where to start drawing edges so the arrows don't overlap with the boxes - is that what you're using it for?

Are you trying to find a way of forcing the 'brain-position' node inside an area?

Please provide a bit more detail of what you're planning and we can probably do this.

Comment: Hi Ben I'm hopping to be able to position on nodes statically with non dynamic x,y coordinates (these would be positioned strategically on an illustration for example on different parts on an anatomical drawing. These nodes would be linked to normal arbor nodes with text on them if that makes sense? thanks.

Comment: PS I think in answer to your question I am trying to fix one node in to an area and have its attached node flaot as close to the edge of the canvas as possible ideally the node lines would not cross?

Comment: Hey, I'm not ignoring you - I will respond, just been a busy few days. You didn't need to accept btw, in fact that will prob just put off other answerers. That said, I'll take a look at this presently. Can start a chat room, maybe that will be easier.

Comment: Hi no worries. Chat room would be good but time differences might get in the way?